# ConstraintLayout inside ScrollView cannot retain constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

Guys, I need to make my `ConstraintLayout` scroll-able, so I placed it inside an `ScrollView` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_margin="64dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/avd"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_min="64dp"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_max="256dp"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But the problem is that I like to scroll layout when all constraints has reached their minimum size(means all controls has reached to their specified margins and layout cannot get smaller anymore). But it seems when `ScrollView` needs to show scrolls, it specifies a very large size for `ConstraintLayout`'s height, so my layout scales up to max possible size. If you try this layout in portrait and then landscape, you notice how it changes.

I wonder if there is any way to start scrolling when all constraint has reached their minimum size. Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: This may be an issue just with your sample that I am seeing. In portrait mode everything looks OK - no scrolling needed. In landscape more, the image is enlarging to such a point that the layout needs to scroll. This is because the width of the image is `0dp` and is constrained to the start/end of the parent. The ratio is 1:1, so the height expands enough to push other items off the screen, so scrolling is needed. If you constrain the max width of the image to something smaller, you will see less need for scrolling.

Comment: @Cheticamp I noticed this myself, but I thought it is more logical that scroll in landscape appears when image size is in 64dp. Why image should upscale to max 256dp? You will notice difference if you set max height constraint to for example 96dp I guess. You will see that whole layout constraints force that image size get smaller and no scroll bar appears. But in our situation that scrollbar need to appear, it seems no height limits is applied and `ConstraitLayout` takes maximum possible height. While it again can downscale image to 64dp and no scroll will be needed again.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are trying to do. Try setting `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"` on the image view to constrain according to the width so the height doesn't blow up.

Comment: @Cheticamp Oh,thanks! So my problem was that `W` character.:) Thanks a lot. Just do you know why if I use `W,1:1`, size whon't get smaller than a specific size? Because if I remove minHeight constraint and use `1:1` Image gets smaller...

Comment: @Cheticamp  In general,I want to see scrollbars only if my `ConstraintLayout` cannot get any smaller height-wise.

Comment: Generally, layouts want to be as big as they can be while respecting constraints. `ScrollView`, in essence, has infinite height and doesn't impose a height restriction on its contents. So, these two things are in conflict in your case. You want the layout to be as big as it can be _and still fit on the screen if it can shrink to do so._ The only thing I can think of is to programmatically make the adjustments you need to make things fit if they can be shrunk to do so.

Comment: @Cheticamp I think found a solution. It *seems* that `ConstraintLayout` really tries to show scrolls in `ScrollView` whenever its constraints are shrinked to the least possible size. But this has a problem `app:layout_constraintHeight_min` which causes oversized expand. So I used `app:layout_constraintWidth_min="64dp" app:layout_constraintHeight_max="256dp" app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"` and now it works as I wanted.

Comment: Sounds good. So minimum height wasn't really required.